# .py to .exe with pyinstaller that can run on any PC

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-3.7

Well, I created a .py file which is a very simple login file. I converted it to exe and works fine on my computer. But when I send it to my friend, he cannot run the exe file because he doesn't have python installed in his pc and bin added to his computer's PATH.

So is there any way to create an exe file that can work on any other computer. Or we should install all the python and its used libraries.

By the way, I am using Python3.7, PyQt5 and pyinstaller for this application

Comment: PyInstaller documentation claims it bundles all the dependencies, including the python runtime, with your program. Did you give your friend this whole package? How did you call pyInstaller? Did you use the `--onefile` option?

Comment: yes i tried ''--onefile'' and also others like ''-w -F''